# Relative Layout, align center of parent and right of view with no overlap

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to align a TextView to be centered in a relative layout but also to the right of an ImageView. I would like it to look like this.

```
[-(image)-----some text here------------]
```

I'm able to do this with the code below, but if the text becomes too long it overlaps the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:contentDescription="@string/abc_search_hint"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/profile"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_connect"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried aligning the TextView to the right of the ImageView but it stops centering in parent if I do that. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does the ImageView need to sit above the TextView and allow the text to populate behind it? Or does it need to be like an image that always sits to the left of the text and the left hand of the TextView is bounded by it?

Comment: @DanielGruici This is a horizontal layout. The image view MUST stay aligned completely left, and the text MUST stay centered in the PARENT layout, NOT the remaining space to the right of the image. The way the current code is it works, UNTIL the text becomes too long then it overlaps the imageview to the left

Comment: Only thing I can think of is a LinearLayout with weights. Create the Horizontal layout with the left being the ImageView, middle being the TextView, and the right being a blank View. Give equal weights to the image and blank view, give the larger weight to the text view. Then the Text gravity can be set, will be centered always, and be bound by the other two views within.

You'll probably have to mess around with the weights to make it look the way you want.

Comment: @DanielGruici ya, i think either way its gonna have to be a hacky kind of work around. If you force one view to be left or right of the other in a relative layout it automatically overides the parent centering. Unfortunate

Comment: Only solution i found is to provide maxLength to text and ellipsize it. So it will not overlap with other views.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm looking for the same. This is the behavior on iOS for action bars. The title is always centered in the parent but it doesn't overlap anything.

Comment: I ended up implementing my own custom layout, extending ViewGroup and overriding onLayout().

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. I used a radio group instead of a linear layout for this but it should still work. Have a the linear layout horizontal as you already do and then make the layout gravity center then just put the image first then the text view

```
<RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="20dp">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_student"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/checkbox_student"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_teacher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/checkbox_teacher"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

            </RadioGroup>
```

EDIT:
I don't know if the margin attributes for the buttons I have work on text views but padding left on the text might work

Comment: My problem is overlapping, not alignment. Also I do not use a linearlayout, I use a relative one. This is so that I can align the textview centered inside of it while also placing the imageview to the left. With so many displays and so many sizes using margins to attempt a work around would not work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:contentDescription="@string/abc_search_hint"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="`enter code here`true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/profile"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_connect"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navMenu"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you cannot set gravity to elements inside a relative layout

Comment: I did, it centers the text inside the TextView. I need to center the TextView inside the parent relative layout.

Comment: forgot somthing, make the TextView layoutWidht = matchparent

Comment: @fahadalawam you're misunderstanding what this person wants. This will still align the text in the center of the `TextView` not the `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You could (and should, for performance sake), use a **compound drawable** for the TextView (and get rid of the ImageView)

You want the image to stay on the Left part of the TextView, so use `android:drawableLeft`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:background="@color/White"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarTitle"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/profile"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_connect"
        android:centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
    />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So the problem here is that this will move the image to the center of the layout as well. If I change the attribute of width to match parent it almost works. However then the text is centered in the remaining space to the right of the imageview. I need the image to stay aligned left and the text to stay centered inside the overall parent layout. Which is why this is tricky